# Print a number in it's text format

Tags: code-golf

This is a classic one.
You get a number from the keyboard from 0 to 1000(including) and must print it in text form.
Examples:

```
Input:5  
Output:five  

Input:23  
Output:twenty three  

Input:999  
Output:nine hundred ninety nine
```